# How to come up with Paypal IPN url?

Tags: meteor, paypal, paypal-ipn

I want to integrate my project with Paypal and it requires a URL before enabling the IPN.

I know this URL for receiving notification posts from Paypal "if am not mistaken" but how do i get it? Do i have to implement a page in my website? if yes what is required from that page? Am really LOST here

Please any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the IPN Listener on your website, since the IPN URL (Notify URL) is a URL you create on your website. 
Make sure that you have an SSL Certificate and the URL Listener is in an https:// format. As of June 2016 all IPN URL Listeners must be in an SSL Format. 
Here is the documentation on [Instant Payment Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)
Here is the documentation on [Creating an IPN Listener](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/)
The documentation will be updated to state that as of June 2016 all listeners must be https://
Here is a link to [IPN Sample Code](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples)
Here is the [IPN Documentation](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1916&expand=true&locale=en_US) on the updates being made in June

Comment: i already went through their documentation. i find it hard to fully get the idea on implementing it. is the listener in the following link is good to be used for meteor project? https://codedump.io/share/24ejikc7Q9s5/1/ipn-listener-for-paypal-in-meteor-app

Comment: the iron:router example on the link. The router will create a path to /ipn. so i just copy that link in the Paypal IPN to enable it?

Comment: The first step is to create the listener, you can use the IPN Sample code to do so. After you create the listener you can house it on your website wherever you'd like. After that you can add the IPN Notify URL to your PayPal Account. You determine the URL for the IPN. Unless you are using a 3rd Party Cart. You determine the IPN Notify URL.

Comment: one last question, are there a way to test the IPN URL without going to production? because the URL would be: "localhost:3000/ipn", or do i have to go to production first?

Comment: Yes, there is an [IPN Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/?mark=IPN%20Simulator) that will allow you to test IPN Responses.